# Remove rows for multiple dataframes having a name matching a pattern

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rbind

I am trying to remove the first 9 rows of multiple dataframes that have the same structures but different names (keeping similar name structure). In my example, there are 4 dataframes with respectively the names 
*Mydataframe_A, Mydataframe_B, Mydataframe_C, Mydataframe_D*.

Currently it is working with the following code:

```
`Mydataframe_A`<- `Mydataframe_A`[-c(1:9),]
`Mydataframe_B`<- `Mydataframe_B`[-c(1:9),]
`Mydataframe_C`<- `Mydataframe_C`[-c(1:9),]
`Mydataframe_D`<- `Mydataframe_D`[-c(1:9),]
```

But I would like to write this is with only one line and not having to specify each time each name of dataframe.

I think this could work by using a pattern name and lists because for example this is what I am doing to rbind different dataframes:

```
All_mydataframes <- rbindlist(mget(ls(pattern = "^Mydataframe_")))
```

Any idea on how to do this ?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `mget` turns this into a list, you can use `apply` family functions:

```
rbindlist(lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^Mydataframe_")), function(x) x[-c(1:9), ]))
```

This takes the `list` from `mget` and removes the first 9 rows, then `rbind` it from list to `data.table`. The only problem is you can't differentiate what `data.frame` the original data was part of.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir !